# Efficiently searching a common node in 2 singly linked lists with a memory constraint?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, runtime, time-complexity

> Suppose you're given two signly-linked lists which ganging up at some point. design a O(n+m) algorithm with use of no more than O(1) memory which finding the **FIRST** common node, where m and n are the distance from the head of the list, to the gang point, respectively.

I thought of marking visited nodes, but then realized that it takes more than O(1) memory.
Problem is easy when you can run on the entire list, which is not allowed here because of runtime limitation. help =D

Comment: Can you explain the definitions of `m` and `n`?  You've only described one of them, and its not clear which.

Comment: Oh, I think I see - you mean the `m` is the distance from the head of one list to the first common node, and `n` is the distance from the head of the other list to the first common node?

Comment: Are we allowed to mutate the original list, as long as it doesn't involve any new allocations?

Comment: You should consider elaborating on what exactly "ganging up" means.

Comment: @AaronDufour Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume there is a way to compare an element `x` from the first list with an element `y` from the second list in a way to find out if they refer to the same element, beyond the gang point.

- Compare `x1` from the first list against `y1` and `y2`, the first two elements of the second list.
- Compare `y1` with `x1` and `x2`.
- Compare `x2` with `y2 ... y4`.
- Compare `y2` with `x2 ... x4`.
- Compare `x4` with `y4 ... y8`.
- ...

In general:

```
for q in 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ...
    Compare x_q with y_q ... y_2q
    Compare y_q with x_q ... x_2q
```

Basically, in each step you double the search range.  Let's say `m <= n`.  Then at some point there is `m<q` and `n-m<q`.  Now you will find a match `x_q==y_(q+n-m)`.  This match is somewhere beyond the gang point, from there you just have to go back to the gang point.  This is `O(n+m)`.

**Edit** OK, the *go back* part doesn't work with a singly linked list.  However, this is a minor technical issue, because at this point we know the difference `n-m` and can start over and search again from the beginning, comparing `x_k` with `y_(k+n-m)` for all `k=1,2,3,...` until we find a match.

**Edit2** The Complexity, a rough overview of the proof.  For each `q` we do `2*q` comparisons.  Let's say we find a match for `q=q1`.  Then summing over all `q` up to `q1` gives `4*q1` comparisons altogether, sum of the geometric series.  Now we just need to prove `q1=O(n+m)`.  We know there is no match up to `q=q1/2`, this means either `m>q1/2` or `n>2*q1/2`, because otherwise there would be a match.  Together this can be writen as `n+m>q1/2` or `q1<2*(n+m)`.  For the number of comparisons we get `4*q1<8*(n+m)`, which is well within `O(n+m)`.  Here we always assume `n>=m`, without loss of generality.  Finally, we have to add the *go back* part, but this is linear as well, so the total algorithm is `O(n+m)` because each part is.

Comment: "you just have to go back to the gang point" is a non-trivial operation (it can be done in `O(n+m)` but its not obvious how).  In fact, "go back" makes it more confusing - you can't traverse a singly-linked list backwards, as that implies.

Comment: Thanks.  I adapted the text.

Comment: Can you explain why this is `O(n+m)`?  It looks like it should be, but I can't prove it.

Comment: Done. Such things are quite cumbersome because for some reason we cannot really write math here.

Comment: We have to find the first common node, In this way, we will find a common node which is not (most of the times) the first common node. If we found that node, how can we find the first one? even if we have to start from the begining? how will we know where to stop?

Comment: @Genadi We compare `x_k` with `y_(k+n-m)` for each `k=1,2,3,...` and stop at the first match.  That's the first common point.

Comment: But what if the first common point does not involve a power of two? E.g., if x[i] = i for i different from 3, and y[i] = -i for i different from 3, and x[3] = y[3] = 0. Then I don't think you will ever find the common point. (This assumes the indices start from 1, as in your code.)

Comment: There will be more common points beyond that first one.  Initially we don't find the first one but some later common point.  Then we start over and check each point and that way we find the first common point.