# How to find a common node of two intersecting linked lists

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, time-complexity, singly-linked-list

We have a project in our Data Structures course and I am stuck with one of the problems.
I could not find any suitable solution for this problem in the web due to the special complexity limitations we where given.
**The Problem:**
let there be two Linked Lists, which intersect after m and n nodes (and continue). the first list has m nodes before the common node and the second one has n nodes up to the common node.
(m and n are not known).
There are two pointers L1, L2 to the first link in each list.
There is NO pointer to the end of any list.
The problem is to find the common node within limitations of O(m+n) [we cant run to the end of any of the links...], with a limit of O(1) additional memory [No option of changing/adding additional data in every link].
The two lists have only pointers pointing forwards (Singly Linked List).
The list pointers can be changed, but the order of the original list needs to be restored.
[although a solution that will ruin the list is also better than nothing].

I am after days of drawing lists and nodes.... losing my mind here :)

Thanks a lot,
Barak.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Efficiently searching a common node in 2 singly linked lists with a memory constraint?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23090601/efficiently-searching-a-common-node-in-2-singly-linked-lists-with-a-memory-const)

Answer (score 0):

You already know the number of elements before the common node in each list.

> ... the first list has m nodes before the common node ...

Just skip that number of nodes in the corresponding list to reach to the common intersecting node.

I am not sure if you are asking the right question here. Kindly update if there is a change in your problem statement.

->Update:
Iterate each list to find its length.
length(List1) = x
length(List2) = y

Let x > y
skip (x-y) nodes on List1.
Traverse List1 and List2 simultaneously and compare the nodes of both the lists. When you find the nodes on both lists to be equal, that will be your point of intersection.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. m and n are unknown. I updated the question.

Comment: Thanks...  I thought about that but I cant iterate through the whole list, because I can only run O(m+n), and they are up to the common node.